# data compare between two different sql servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently migrating data from an SQL 2008 R2 to SQL 2014 server and want to check that all data values in the destination server is identical to what is in the source server post migration. However, the two servers are on different network segments. What are some ways I can compare data between two different sql servers?

Comment: Do you want to check record count and data of all table objects in the database

Comment: Visual Studio & SSDT has a data compare tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Answer (score 0):

You can write a hash-function for each table individually. And then just compare the values.

Example of a simple implementation of this function for MSSQL:

```
SELECT
AVG(CAST(CAST(
            HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT(columnn1, column2, column3))
    AS BIGINT) AS FLOAT)) 
FROM simpleTable;
```

And the same for MySql:

```
SELECT 
AVG(CONV(SUBSTR(MD5(CONCAT(column1, column2, column3)),
             1, 16),
      16, 10))
FROM simpleTable;
```

Comment: Not sure how a mysql function is going to help here. This is clearly tagged with sql server. This is invalid code in sql server.

Comment: @SeanLange, I rewrote query for sql server. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to compare between the two databases, but you should have no problem creating a linked server to get what you need... just be sure to delete the linked server when you're done using it since it does pose a security concern.
http://learnsqlwithbru.com/2012/01/06/create-linked-server-to-connect-to-another-sql-server-part-i/

You could also use Service Broker which is more secure, but a bit more involved as well.
https://serverfault.com/questions/98084/can-i-setup-a-link-sql-server-connection-between-servers-on-different-networks